Why is JAX so slow?
I started playing with JAX recently, as swap for numpy, and I was not giving much thought into testing if it is really better than numpy, till I have started exploring vectorization, and found this article: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/numpy/vectorization giving examples with numpy, and claiming that using arrays is faster than looping.
I would not have any problem with that claim, except that their example was showing something completely opposite!? Iterating in loop and adding numbers to list is faster than doing that in array?! Output for loop time: For loop time: 4.76837158203125e-06 and output for vec time: Vectorization time: 1.5020370483398438e-05. That 4.768e-06 is clearly smaller than: 1.502e-05.
This led me to try to replicate that experiment. So I wrote this simple code comparing for loops, numpy and jax:
import numpy as np
import jax.numpy as jnp
import time

array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for n in range(20):
    start = time.time()
    result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for i in range(len(result)):
        result[i] += 10
    end = time.time()

loop_time = end - start
print("For loop time:", loop_time, "array1: ", result)

array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])

for n in range(20):
    start = time.time()
    result_np = array1 + 10
    end = time.time()

vec_time = end - start
print("Vec time:     ", vec_time, "result: ", result_np)

array1 = jnp.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ])

for n in range(20):
    start = time.time()
    result_jax = array1 + 10
    end = time.time()

jax_time = end - start
print("Jax vec time:", jax_time, "result: ", result_jax)

To give even chances to jax, I have ran same operation 20 times in the loop, measuring only the time of the last operation. Running it once does not really benefit JAX nor numpy, both seems to optimize if you run same operation multiple times. (My educated guess is that numpy does not have to allocate memory, and JAX does some other magic with its compiler behind the scenes).
I have tried different number of loops, initialization etc. However output I get each time:
For loop time: 1.9073486328125e-06 array1:  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Vec time:      2.384185791015625e-06 result:  [11 12 13 14 15]
Jax vec time: 9.083747863769531e-05 result:  [11 12 13 14 15]

This shows clearly JAX is left so behind numpy and loops.
This would be too far-fetched to say, that JAX is worse, but it makes me wonder: if JAX is not performing any better on such a basic example, then how can we utilize it to outperform numpy or simple looping? (Btw, it runs on CUDA). Could you recommend some examples to try?

That article is pretty terrible. They're using tiny inputs, below the point where NumPy provides any benefit, and they're recommending numpy.vectorize as if it's a performance feature - it's not. It's basically a wrapper around a for loop.

You need to use larger arrays to see any benefit from NumPy, and I'd guess you'd need much larger arrays to see any benefit from JAX.

This question comes up frequently enough that JAX has an entry for it in the FAQ: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-jax-faster-than-numpy

Quoting from JAX FAQ: is JAX faster than NumPy?:

...in summary: if you’re doing microbenchmarks of individual array operations on CPU, you can generally expect NumPy to outperform JAX due to its lower per-operation dispatch overhead. If you’re running your code on GPU or TPU, or are benchmarking more complicated JIT-compiled sequences of operations on CPU, you can generally expect JAX to outperform NumPy.

Your benchmark script is squarely in the regime where we'd expect JAX to be slower than NumPy due to its per-operation disptach cost. In practice, this dispatch overhead isn't all that important, because any real-world program of interest will be much more involved than just five integer additions.
